# How to deal with this joint variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I have a gaussian random variable $X$ ~ $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I then defined $n$ new variables $Y_j$ by
$$
Y_j = a_j + (X - b_j)^2,
$$
where $a_j$ and $b_j$ are some defined positive constants. So the $Y_j$ are clearly **dependent**.
For some positive constant $C$, I have to develop the probability $P(\min_j Y_j > C)$.

I did the following steps, but I was told this is not correct.

\begin{align*}
P(\min_j Y_j > C) &= P( (Y_1,...,Y_n) > (C,...,C))\\
&= P( (X-b_1)^2,...,(X-b_n)^2) > (C-a_1,...,C-a_n))\\
&= P( |X-b_1|,...,|X-b_n|) > (\sqrt{C-a_1},...,\sqrt{C-a_n}))\\
&= P( (X,...,X) >  (\sqrt{C-a_1} + b_1,...,\sqrt{C-a_n} + b_n)) + P( (X,...,X) <  (-\sqrt{C-a_1} + b_1,...,-\sqrt{C-a_n} + b_n))\\
&= P(X > \max_j (\sqrt{C-a_j} + b_j) + P(X < \min_j (-\sqrt{C-a_j} + b_j)
\end{align*}

So, from which equality is this false? And why? I guess this is the absolute value that I cannot develop this way for a joint variable, but why not?

What would be the right way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that either $X>\sqrt {C-a_j} +b_j$ for all $j$ or $X<-\sqrt {C-a_j} +b_j$ for all $j$. It could be the first inequality for some $j$ and the other inequality for other $j$'s.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand, thanks again! But what should I do then ?

Comment: You will have consider any subset $I$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and apply the first inequality for $i\in i$ the second inequality for $ i \notin I$ and sum over all $I$. I donn't think you can get a simple expression as your answer.